# Cannot render nested object array using map - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

my json file as the following structure:

```
export interface IProject {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  environments: [
    {
      name: string;
      assembled: string;
      snapshotversion: string;
    }
  ];
}
```

The function below renders a list of the json data:

```
const Project = ({ project }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Flex flexDirection="column">
      <ul>
        <li>Project Id: {project.id}</li>
        <li>
          Environments:{' '}
          {project.environments.map((data, index) => {
            <Box key={index}>
              <li>Name: {data.name}</li>
              <li>Assembled: {data.assembled}</li>
              <li>Snapshot Version: {data.snapshotversion}</li>
            </Box>;
          })}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

I am able to return the correct json data, but cannot render the nested properties in "environments"

Comment: In your `Project` function, if you put a `console.log(project)` before the `return` statement, what shows?

Comment: Hello Keith, that returns "undefined" but not sure why as it is rendering the remaining properties correctly

Comment: In that case I'm assuming it's an `async` issue.   Are you using `fetch` with `useEffect / setState`?, if your already doing that you might just need to put `if (!project) return null` in the same place you put the `console.log`, and then it will render on the second pass.

Comment: Thank you, yep I added the if condition in but I am still getting undefined? Im using useeffect/set state I will update my post to display these

Comment: Yes, you will still get `undefined`, until you call some sort of `setState` in your `useEffect`,..  Your not showing the code were you load the `project`, it might be best including that too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not returned the JSX in the array.map.
To fix this just replace the `{` with `(`.
See the line containing: `project.environments.map`

```
const Project = ({ project }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Flex flexDirection="column">
      <ul>
        <li>Project Id: {project.id}</li>
        <li>Lifecyle Id: {project.lifecycleName}</li>
        <li>
          Environments:{' '}
          {project.environments.map((data, index) => (
            <Box key={index}>
              <li>Name: {data.name}</li>
              <li>Assembled: {data.assembled}</li>
              <li>Snapshot Version: {data.snapshotversion}</li>
            </Box>;
          ))}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

The correct syntax is:

```
{project.environments.map((data, index) => ( <div>some jsx</div>))}
```

or

```
{project.environments.map((data, index) => {
    return (<div>some jsx</div>)
  })}
```

Comment: Great thank you that works now!